# Convert list of interfaces from show vlan into full name list line by line

Tags: python, bash, interface, show, vlan

I need to take list of interfaces from show vlan:

```
gi1/0/1, gi1/0/2, gi1/0/3, gi1/0/5, gi1/0/7, gi1/0/10
gi1/0/11, gi1/0/13, gi1/0/15, gi1/0/17, gi1/0/19
```

and get the text output as

```
interface gi 1/0/1
...
interface gi 1/0/19
```

I got my original input as a list using following code:

```
cisco1 ="""gi1/0/1, gi1/0/2, gi1/0/3, gi1/0/5, gi1/0/7, gi1/0/10
gi1/0/11, gi1/0/13, gi1/0/15, gi1/0/17, gi1/0/19
gi1/0/21, gi1/0/31, gi1/0/32, gi1/0/33, gi1/0/34, gi1/0/35, gi1/0/40"""
list1 = cisco1.split()
print(list1)
```

This gives me a list with extra commas (not every time).

```
['gi1/0/1,', 'gi1/0/2,', 'gi1/0/3,', 'gi1/0/5,', 'gi1/0/7,', 'gi1/0/10', 'gi1/0/11,', 'gi1/0/13,', 'gi1/0/15,', 'gi1/0/17,', 'gi1/0/19', 'gi1/0/21,', 'gi1/0/31,', 'gi1/0/32,', 'gi1/0/33,', 'gi1/0/34,', 'gi1/0/35,', 'gi1/0/40']
```

I would like to take each record and remove comma (if its there) and replace "gi" with "int gi"
Any help in bash of python would be appreciated.

Update:
I came up with this code but i still need to print each int in separate line and add "int " in front of "gi".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cisco1="gi1/0/1, gi1/0/2, gi1/0/3, gi1/0/5, gi1/0/7, gi1/0/10
gi1/0/11, gi1/0/13, gi1/0/15, gi1/0/17, gi1/0/19
gi1/0/21, gi1/0/31, gi1/0/32, gi1/0/33, gi1/0/34, gi1/0/35, gi1/0/40"

tr -d ',' <<<$cisco1 | tr ' ' '\n'| awk '{ print "interface gi " substr($1,3)}'
# ^remove commas       ^blanks to newlines   

interface gi 1/0/1
interface gi 1/0/2
interface gi 1/0/3
interface gi 1/0/5
interface gi 1/0/7
interface gi 1/0/10
interface gi 1/0/11
interface gi 1/0/13
interface gi 1/0/15
interface gi 1/0/17
interface gi 1/0/19
interface gi 1/0/21
interface gi 1/0/31
interface gi 1/0/32
interface gi 1/0/33
interface gi 1/0/34
interface gi 1/0/35
interface gi 1/0/40



var1="no shut";
var2="shut"; 
tr -d ',' <<<$cisco1 | tr ' ' '\n'| awk -v str="$var1" '{ printf "interface gi %s \n", substr($1,3); printf "%s\n", str }'

interface gi 1/0/1
no shut
interface gi 1/0/2
no shut

tr -d ',' <<<$cisco1 | tr ' ' '\n'| awk -v str="$var2" '{ printf "interface gi %s \n", substr($1,3); printf "%s\n", str }'

interface gi 1/0/1
shut
interface gi 1/0/2
shut
```

Comment: how do i add "shut" and "no shut" in between so the output looks like this:
interface gi 1/0/11
shut
no shut

Comment: @Robbo_3542 shut no shut added

Comment: Thank you for quick response.
Any way i could use variables instead of prinf "string" ? like this?

var1="shut"
tr -d ',' <<<$cisco1 | tr ' ' '\n'| awk '{ printf "interface gi %s \n", substr($1,3); printf $var1}'

Comment: @Robbo_3542  answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple delimiters in your string.

use regular expression.

```
import re

cisco1 ="""gi1/0/1, gi1/0/2, gi1/0/3, gi1/0/5, gi1/0/7, gi1/0/10
gi1/0/11, gi1/0/13, gi1/0/15, gi1/0/17, gi1/0/19
gi1/0/21, gi1/0/31, gi1/0/32, gi1/0/33, gi1/0/34, gi1/0/35, gi1/0/40"""

list1 = re.split(r',|\n|", ";', cisco1)

print(list1)
```

for replacing you can use list comprehension.

```
finalList = [x.replace("gi","int gi").strip() for x in list1]

print(finalList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pavan. This helped me a lot.
Here is final code:

```
import re
cisco1 ="""gi1/0/1, gi1/0/2, gi1/0/3, gi1/0/5, gi1/0/7, gi1/0/10
gi1/0/11, gi1/0/13, gi1/0/15, gi1/0/17, gi1/0/19
gi1/0/21, gi1/0/31, gi1/0/32, gi1/0/33, gi1/0/34, gi1/0/35, gi1/0/40"""
list11 = re.split(r',|\n|", ";', cisco1)
finalList = [x.replace("gi","int gi").strip() for x in list11]
print(finalList)
for x in finalList:
    print(x)
```

final lines of output are:

```
int gi1/0/34
int gi1/0/35
int gi1/0/40
```